# Chrome doesn't load IFrame pages using Colorbox plugin

Tags: google-chrome, colorbox

I'm using Colorbox to display pages in a modal window format. This plugin works fine in Firefox, but when I click on the same link on the same page in Chrome, it just opens it up as a standard page. It doesn't load it in a modal style.

The plugin is being loaded, and no errors are given. Is there a bug with Colorbox when being used with Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my html, I had the link to the colorbox.js file below a call for lightbox.js:

```
<script src="/js/lightbox.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
```

Swapping them round like this:

```
<script src="/js/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script src="/js/lightbox.js"></script>
```

Solved the problem!